# Delay in changing Azure AD permissions for Microsoft Graph with certificate?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We're adding permissions in an Azure AD application for Microsoft Graph  that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried to remove all permissions from another already working app and it still works without any permissions assigned all.

Is there any known delays when updating permissions? (We're using application permissions with certificates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that it seems to be a delay. After more than 2 hours and no changes it started working as expected.

Comment: After waiting 4 hours I got in touch with a second o365 admin of ours.  Turns out even when an admin grants heavier permissions like "send mail as any user" they still have to go back and *also* click on a "grant permissions" button.  The first admin didn't know that trick, and my second admin did.  The new roles showed up in my jwt tokens 5 mins later and all good now.

Answer (score 0):

With the v1 Endpoint, you can force changes to scopes by adding `prompt=consent` to your authentication URL.

Note that if the new permission requires Admin Consent, that will also need to be reapplied.

Comment: Even for application permissions? I granted all permissions directly in Azure profile just to be sure. It started working 2-3 hours with no change from our send so seems to be a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the issue here Jonas.  I'm assuming that you either went through a consent experience for your app (as Marc is indicated that you can force) OR that in the Azure Portal, after making app configuration changes, that you clicked on "Grant Permissions"?  To be clear, changing app configuration only changes the permissions your app is **requesting**.  These permissions still need to be granted (either through consent or in the app's tenant through the Grant Permissions button in the Azure Portal) - simply changing the app config does not re-grant permissions.

So assuming that permissions were re-granted, is this where you are seeing delays in the grant update taking place?  If so, please can you send us the full error that you are seeing (client-request-id and timestamp) and we can take a look.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I'm an administrator so we didn't go through any admin consent but everything was granted immediately. The issue was that it didn't take effect after hours so seems to be an issue in the underlying Microsoft system. The issue was present across multiple applications and subscriptions for various clients as we tested to make sure it wasn't specific to just this application.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Please confirm that you clicked on "Grant Permissions" in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Yes I did. I am 100% sure, I manage this kind of things on a daily basis.

Comment: In which case, can you repro the issue please.  For an app that has some permissions, or a new app, please "grant permissions" and then try and use the app.  If it errors please update your question with the full error message (timestamp and client-request-id).  Doing this the other way (removing permissions) will be difficult for us to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks. We Do have a have a ticket in Partner Support for this.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT I can corroborate that this is happening to us as well. It takes a long time for the changes in permissions to propagate. Granting permissions has nothing to do with it. [This is not the only post on SO about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36320767/1200185).